# Spring boot log secret.yaml from helm

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes-helm

I am getting started with helm. I have defined the deployment, service, configMap and secret yaml files.

I have a simple spring boot application with basic http authentication, the username and password are defined in the secret file.

My application is correctly deployed, and when I tested it in the browser, it tells me that the username and password are wrong.

Is there a way to know what are the values that spring boot receives from helms?

Or is there a way to decrypt the secret.yaml file?

values.yaml

```
image:
  repository: myrepo.azurecr.io
  name: my-service
  tag: latest 

replicaCount: 1

users:
  - name: "admin"
    password: "admintest"
    authority: "admin"
  - name: "user-test"
    password:  "usertest"
    authority: "user"

spring:
  datasource:
    url: someurl
    username: someusername
    password: somepassword
    platform: postgresql
```

secret.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}-secret
stringData:
  spring.datasource.url: "{{ .Values.spring.datasource.url }}"
  spring.datasource.username: "{{ .Values.spring.datasource.username }}"
  spring.datasource.password: "{{ .Values.spring.datasource.password }}"
  spring.datasource.platform: "{{ .Values.spring.datasource.platform }}"  
  {{- range $idx, $user := .Values.users }}
  users_{{ $idx }}_.name: "{{ $user.name }}"
  users_{{ $idx }}_.password: "{{ printf $user.password }}"
  users_{{ $idx }}_.authority: "{{ printf $user.authority }}"
  {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the secret in the secret.yaml file won't be encrypted, just encoded in base64. So you could decode the content of the secret in tool like https://www.base64decode.org/ If you've got access to the kubernetes dashboard that also provides a way to see the value of the secret.

If you're injecting the secret as [environment variables](https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/secrets-treasurehunt/blob/master/charts/treasurehunt/templates/deployment.yaml#L35) then you can find the pod with `kubeclt get pods` and then `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` will include output of which environment variables are injected.

With helm I find it very useful to run `helm install --dry-run --debug` as then you can see in the console exactly what kubernetes resources will be created from the template for that install.

Comment: Is pretty strange, I printed the values from the secret file. It has the expected credentials, but still I am having problems to access the application, it asks again for the username and password. I am going to add my value.yaml and secret.yaml with test values

Comment: Are the secrets being injected as environment variables or used to make a properties file that is mounted in the Pod? Either way maybe you can `kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -- /bin/bash` into the pod and use the shell to see what it sees (either by echoing the env var or doing a `more` on the file). Though if it fails during startup then you might only have a short window in which to exec in. Possibly you could buy yourself more time to exec in by temporarily hardcoding to make sure it starts and enable yourself to debug more.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the shell, I run the command but which commands I should execute? or could you provide me a link reference to inspect the pod. The values are injected as variables for the property file, I have my application.properties file with the same values as the secret (the database credentials and the username/password). Could you suggest me some techniques to debug? where exactly I should debug?

Comment: If it's going inside your properties file from the values.yaml then you need to be mounting the properties file in the Pod. That means your Deployment resource should contain a `volumeMounts` section that mounts to `/config` and a `volumes` section that references the secret. I'd start by checking that. (You can find some explanation of this in 'Taking the Game to Minikube' in https://dzone.com/articles/hunting-treasure-with-kubernetes-configmaps-and-se though note that's a configmap example so the syntax is a little different for secrets). Including the volume and mount in q would be cool.

Comment: Once you've run `kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -- /bin/bash` then you should be able to do `cd /config` and then `more application.properties`. For the syntax for mounting secrets - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178683/discussion-between-andreahg-and-ryan-dawson).

Comment: do you have your project in Github?

Comment: yes it is https://github.com/ryandawsonuk/secrets-treasurehunt I guess I should say I've assumed you're not using https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes

Comment: Thank you, no, I am not using cloud kubernetes

Comment: I just realized that the deployment.yaml is using envFrom to get the environment variables. What else I should consider?

Comment: In that case I think you need to change the entry names to uppercase with underscores rather than lowercase with dots. So SPRING_ rather than spring.